# Msqli, how group "graphically" a query from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

- table 1) `courses_cat` (this one have a "title" field)
- table 2) `courses` (this one have a "parent" field which I want use to "group", this "parent" is equal to "title"

So I need to put "graphically" the content of the table 2 inside the table 1.

Here my code (separated for both tables):

```
<?php
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT title, body, showeb, datapost FROM courses_cat WHERE showeb="si"');
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($title, $body, $showeb, $datapost);
while ($query->fetch())

echo " <div class='pblock'><h2>$title</h2><pre>$body</pre></div> "; 
?>

<?php
$query2 = $db->prepare('SELECT parent, title, body, showeb, datapost FROM courses WHERE showeb="si"');
 $query2->execute();
 $query2->store_result();
 $query2->bind_result($parent, $title, $body, $showeb, $datapost);
 while ($query2->fetch())

 echo " <div id='courseblock'><a href='#'><span class='top'>$title</span><span class='content'>$shortbody</span></a></div>"; 
?>
```

Comment: What does "graphically" mean here?

Comment: So it sound like you are trying to group these courses by category with course listed within each category?  Do you mean that `courses.parent` has an equal value to `courses_cat.title`?  If so, you like just want to get all this information with a single query across a join.

Comment: I tried to explain better what is my problem (see below), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my working code (simple version) for what I needed...

```
<?php
$cat = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT title AS catTitle, body AS catBody FROM courses_cat");
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT parent, title, shortbody FROM courses");

//array x categories
$category = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat)) {$category[] = $row;}

//array x courses
$course = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {$course[] = $row;}

// here my divs
$cat_div="";
foreach ($category as $row) {  
$cat_div = $row['catTitle'];
echo "<div class='pblock'>";
echo "<h2>".$row['catTitle']."</h2><pre>".$row['catBody']."</pre>";

foreach ($course as $row) {
if ($cat_div == $row['parent']) {
echo "<div id='courseblock'><a href='#'><span class='top'>".$row['title']."</span><span> class='content'>".$row['shortbody']."</span></a></div>";}}
echo "</div>";}

$cat->free_result();
$result->free_result();
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what the end result should be, but I'm sure you can merge your two queries into one; looping over this properly might solve your issue:

```
SELECT cat.title as CatTitle, cat.body as CatBody, courses.title as CourseTitle, courses.body as CourseBody -- and any other fields you need like that
FROM courses_cat cat, courses
WHERE cat.parent = courses.title
GROUP BY cat.title
```

Comment: Your query works ok, in part, see below what is that I need…THX

Comment: I answered the question you asked, but you chose as the correct answer... another question??

Comment: Sorry Chris my bad (for the answered question)… I didn't resolve the question yet…as I said, below I try to explain better my problem.

Comment: Yes it seems like you're saying "write my php for me to get this output". Try doing it, and if you can't solve something, open a new question with what you're stuck on.

Comment: See Chris, I did not mean that at all, are 4 days that I'm "puzzling" to figure out how to do this (with my little knowledge of mysql), but if you prefer to think so is up to you...I also posted my edited code (with part of the query that you give me somedays ago..) I don't want/need the complete php code, just the query (if exist a way to do that with a query) but at this point I think that need some "forech"...or fetch assoc...or what...

Answer (score 0):

I try the code posted by Digital Chris, and it works (in part), for explain better, the follow code (see below the edited one) "group ok the categories and put the items inside" but I need to get more of one Course (div "courseblock") into each Category (div "pblock") and this code print just one…(I think it "break the loop" and maybe need to JOIN the data of the "courses" into their "categories")
At this link can see an graphic example of what I mean:
http://liberartestudio.com/download/aaa.jpg
***(the category blocks are those whites, the courses those red)***
Here the link to the page:
http://lvdsys.liberartestudio.com/services_courses.php

```
 <?php
 $query = $db->prepare(' 
SELECT courses_cat.title AS CatTitle, courses_cat.body AS CatBody, courses_cat.datapost AS CatData, courses.parent, courses.title AS CourseTitle, courses.shortbody AS CourseShortbody, courses.datapost AS CourseData 
FROM courses_cat, courses 
WHERE courses_cat.title = courses.parent 
GROUP BY parent 
ORDER BY CatData AND CourseData
');
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($CatTitle, $CatBody, $CatData, $parent, $CourseTitle, $CourseShortbody, $CourseData);
while ($query->fetch())
echo "
<div class='pblock'>
<h2>$CatTitle</h2><pre>$CatBody</pre>
<div id='courseblock'><a href='#'><span class='top'>$CourseTitle</span><span class='content'>$CourseShortbody</span></a>
</div>
</div>
"; ?>
```